# Loop over NumPy array row/column and modify the values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,0]]) 
for x in A[1,:]:
    if x < failure_tolerance:
         x = 0
```

This obviously doesnt work because there is some thing going on with writeability but I can't get behind it.

Comment: any error is there?

Comment: @ChandaKorat: well obviously nothing changes in `A`, so that means that the code has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that here only `x` is altered. `x` does *not* refer to a specific cell in the array, it holds a reference to an element in the array (but not the cell that holds the element).

Nevertheless usually one uses numpy structures when you want to perform calculations on matrices in *bulk*:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,0]]) 
A[1,A[1,:] < failure_tolerance] = 0
```

Here `A[1,:] < failure_tolerance` will construct a mask of values that are less than the `failure_tolerance`. Next we set `0` to all those values in `A`.

For example (with `failure_tolerance = 5`):

```
>>> failure_tolerance = 5
>>> A[1,A[1,:] < failure_tolerance] = 0
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 0]])
```

As you can see the first element of the second row (`4`) is now replaced by `0` since it is smaller than `5`.

Usually when you perform calls with numpy, it will run faster since numpy does not do these calls in Python, but uses high performance datastructures and algorithms in a C. For (very) small matrices there won't be any difference (it is possible that numpy will take longer because of the call overhead), but if you work with huge matrices, numpy will definitely outperform any solution written in Python.

Furthermore this syntax is quite declarative: a trained numpy developer will immediately understand that you set values that are less than the `failure_tolerance`.

**EDIT**:

In case you want multiple conditions, you can use `|` as a logical or and `&` as a logical and. For instance:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,0]]) 
A[1,(A[1,:] < failure_tolerance) & (A[1,:] > at_least_value)] = 0
```

This will set all values of the *second* row of `A` to `0` given those values are between `at_least_value` and `failure_tolerance`.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate multiple conditions? Like: Alter the element if it is smaller than failure_tolerance AND bigger than at_least_value

Comment: A[dst, A[dst,:] < ETA & A[dst,:] > -ETA] = 0                                        │ 20                                                                                 
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could n│ 21 def swap_row(A, swap1, swap2):                                                  
ot be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: A is of elements of type float64

Comment: @JoschKraus: yeah sorry, you need to add brackets.

Comment: Perfect, works like pie. Can you give me some name, some topic, something I can hit google up with or some reference where I can inform myself further on the technique that you used to solve the problem? (Will accept your answer once the minimum acceptance time runs out)